# Can drools5.x and drools6.x be run in the same application

Tags: drools

Currently our application is on Drools5.x and we are planning to migrate to Drools6.x and planning to do it phase wise. Is it possible to run both engines in the same application? HAving two jars of different version on classpath might cause runtime problems.

Any reply is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it looks as if it should be possible.

All of the stable API of Drools 5 is in and below package `org.drools`, whereas the stable API of Drools 6 is in and below package `org.kie`.

But all the internal classes of Drools have remained below package `org.drools`. This provides ample room for clashes, and I would recommend not trying to run both versions in the same application. To say nothing about the third-party libraries used by Drools.

However, it should be possible to set up a *separate* application running a session using Drools 6 (or Drools 5) while the main application runs another session using Drools 5 (or Drools 6). The separate app receives facts and returns results using standard message passing techniques, which should keep the interface simple enough. Building two applications with different Drools libraries is a relatively simple CM exercise.

Finally I would not shy away from migrating in one step. DRL files remain compatible unless you have been using very exotic features, and the usual API for compiling DRL and starting sessions is easily migrated.